# How to create a dictionary of series with an index from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, series, dictionary-comprehension

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['Animal','Deer','Sheep','Fish','Vehicle','Truck','Car','Mineral','Gold','Silver'], 
                   'col_2': ['Animal',0.5,0.25,0.25,'Vehicle',0.5,0.5,'Mineral',0.75,0.25],
                   'Group': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2]})
```

I want to create a dictionary of series. I want column 1 to be the index, column 2 the value and Group to specify the series. EG the name (key) for the first series would be "Animal" and it should look like:
[image]

I've tried the following. But it's not right, I'm getting a dictionary of dataframes instead of series and the headers are in the first row.

```
dict_of_series = {i: df.loc[df.group == i, ['col_1', 'col_2']] for i in range(1, df.group.iat[-1])}
```

Comment: Can you put your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dictionary comprhension for [loop by `groupby` object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) with [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) for set columnsnames by first row per groups, remove first row and last column by indexing in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last remove columns names in [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) :

```
dict_of_series = {g['col_2'].iat[0]: 
                  g.set_axis(g.iloc[0], axis=1).iloc[1:, :-1].rename_axis(None, axis=1) 
                  for i, g in df.groupby('Group')} 


print (dict_of_series['Animal'])
  Animal Animal
1   Deer    0.5
2  Sheep   0.25
3   Fish   0.25

print (dict_of_series['Vehicle'])
  Vehicle Vehicle
5   Truck     0.5
6     Car     0.5

print (dict_of_series['Mineral'])
  Mineral Mineral
8    Gold    0.75
9  Silver    0.25
```

For Series use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) before solution and also change `iloc` for select last column to `Series` and last [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.set_index('col_1')

dict_of_series = {g['col_2'].iat[0]: 
                  g.set_axis(g.iloc[0], axis=1).iloc[1:, 0].rename_axis(None)
                  for i, g in df.groupby('Group')} 


print (dict_of_series['Animal'])
Deer      0.5
Sheep    0.25
Fish     0.25
Name: Animal, dtype: object
```

Comment: works perfect, can you help me understand the dictionary comprehension? For example, what does "i, g in df.groupby('Group')" do?  How does python know what is i and what is g? and I'm use to putting an aggregator at the end of the groupby.

Comment: This is a dictionary of dataframes and I'm looking for a dictionary of series.  How do I move the first column over to the index within the comprehension?

Comment: @JonathanHay - You are right, description was missing. Added to answer also for generate Series like need.

Comment: How would this be modified to handle an additional series that only had one element (eg Beef is turned into an integer and lost)? For example df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['Animal','Deer','Sheep','Fish','Vehicle','Truck','Car','Mineral','Gold','Silver','Meat',Beef], 
                   'col_2': ['Animal',0.5,0.25,0.25,'Vehicle',0.5,0.5,'Mineral',0.75,0.25,'Meat',1],
                   'Group': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]})

Comment: @JonathanHay - I have to go away, sorry. Can you post new question with link to this solution? I have full weekend, so in Monday can check it.