# Creating a dictionary of series from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that I want to turn into a dictionary of series.
Here is my dataframe and existing line of code that works except in one case (when the series has only one item).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': ['Fruit', 'Apple', 'Pear','Orange','Vegtable','Pea','Lettus','Meat','Beef'],
                   'col_2': ['Fruit', .25, .25,.5,'Vegtable',.6,.4,'Meat',1],
                   'group':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]})

dict_of_series = {g['col_2'].iat[0]:g.set_axis(g.iloc[0], axis=1).set_axis(g['col_1']).iloc[1:, 1:-1].squeeze() for i, g in df.groupby('group')}
```

[image]

[image]

The code works as long as a group has three rows, but occasionally I have 2 (as in meat where my beef value is disappearing).  Specifically, this is what i want it to look like...
[image]

Thank you
PS Here is a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290662/how-to-create-a-dictionary-of-series-with-an-index-from-a-dataframe-in-python/70290983?noredirect=1#comment127323315_70290983)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
output = {x.iat[0,0]: pd.Series(x.set_index("col_1").iloc[1:,0], name=x.iat[0,0]) for _, x in df.groupby("group")}

>>> output
{'Fruit': col_1
 Apple     0.25
 Pear      0.25
 Orange     0.5
 Name: Fruit, dtype: object,
 'Vegtable': col_1
 Pea       0.6
 Lettus    0.4
 Name: Vegtable, dtype: object,
 'Meat': col_1
 Beef    1
 Name: Meat, dtype: object}
```

Comment: This allows for a 1 element series (great!), but unfortunately, it loses the informative index. For example, in the original code the Fruit Series has an index of "Apple", "Pear", "Orange', but your index is now 1,2,3. Do you know how to bring that back?

Comment: so close, originally col_2 is renamed to match the Key name.  Is it possible to do this too?